# Rounding behavior when NSNumberFormatter reads string?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have this sample code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *numberString = @"9.2";
NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:numberString];
NSLog(@"String: %@, Number: %@", numberString, number);
```

The printed result is:

```
String: 9.2, Number: 9.199999999999999
```

I don't understand why this would happen. Am I missing a setting?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point numbers. The closest `double` to 9.2 is actually 9.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875.

Comment: It looks as if the formatter is converting it to a float in order to create the number....  Odd

Comment: Because he isn't using a float?

Comment: Hmm, strange that I haven't run into this before. Is there someplace I can read more about this?

Comment: @lnafziger What is an `NSNumber` for a type?

Comment: @DanielFischer an NSObject?  It doesn't specify a storage type but can store representations of many different types...

Comment: Internally I believe it's still storing it as a double, so if there are accuracy issues they would show through there as well.

Comment: While I didn't realize that NSNumber stored as a double, here is an answer that I gave on another question that explains why you get what you have:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10049569/937822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this reference](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSNumber), an `NSNumber` can store any ordinary C numeric type. Since this is obtained by parsing a non-integer, the two types to choose from are `float` and `double`, and by the displayed value, the chosen representation is `double`.

Since decimal fractions like 9.2 aren't exactly representable as `double`s, you get the closest representable number. That is displayed to default precision, which is about 16 decimal places.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I knew there were issues with very large or very small numbers, but didn't expect an issue like that for a seemingly-average sized number like that. Anyway thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: The size doesn't matter, most numbers cannot be exactly represented in either decimal representation (`NSDecimalNumber`) or base 2 (what `float` and `double` use). However, the inexactness is usually very small and doesn't matter (if it does, though, things get hairy), so for 99.99% of applications at least one of `NSNumber` and `NSDecimalNumber` does fine.