# Floating Point things work.....Most of the time

Tags: objective-c, ios, floating-point, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correcting floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049533/correcting-floating-point-numbers)

```
float randNum = arc4random()%(100)-1;
```

I read somewhere that this will give me random numbers between 1-100.  Or something close to that.

This line seems to work all the time, but I convert this number to an NSString for storage/printing to text, and then convert it back to a float for ordering and other calculations.  But when I get that float back sometimes it looks something like gibberish; like this in the variable view:

```
9   float   9.75303731e-41
```

Why would converting to an NSString and back to a float ruin the float value I'm using? (e.g. What could I have screwed up? Or should I be using CGFloat instead?)

I think this is all the pertinent code:

```
NSMutableArray *stringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
floatArray[30];
// put three random floats into an NSMutableArray of NSStrings
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    float randNum = arc4random()%(100)-1;
    NSString *randString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", randNum];
    [stringArray addObject:randString];
}

// convert NSStrings back to float
for(NSString *string in stringArray)
{
    float temp = [string floatValue];
    floatArray[iterator] = temp;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

EDIT:  When I step through the code it looks like the float value looks sane until the line "float temp = [string floatValue]", which is where the value seems to be garbaged.

Comment: Instead of converting to NSString, why dont you convert to NSNumber and save it in array and then get it back from NSNumber object?

Comment: ACB - Thanks for the suggestion.  I will try that out.
Inafziger - Thanks for posting the possible duplicate.  I will try out ACB's suggestion.

Comment: Why are you subtracting 1? `arc4random()%(100)` returns a number from 0-99, so you should _add_ 1 to shift up to 1-100.

Comment: Again, code I had found online.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using float when the result from arc4random() is a uint32_t?  Switching to integer types would almost certainly get around all this, as I suspect the problem is because of the conversion to string form allowing only 3 significant digits.  What happens if you use %.15f as your format?

Sidenote: use arc4random_uniform() - it's simpler and guaranteed to be a uniformly random distribution within that range.